# how to calculate the $\dim(W_1\cap W_2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

[image]

> My Ans is 2. But my friend is claiming that ans is 1. Can anybody provide me the correct solution. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $U, V$ linear subspaces of a vector space $E$ you have
$$\dim(U + V) = \dim(U) + \dim(V) - \dim(U \cap V)$$

Here $E = \mathcal M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb R)$ and $\dim \mathcal M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb R) = 4$. Also you can prove that $\dim W_1 =2$ and $\dim W_2 =3$.

You can prove that $\dim(W_1+W_2) = 4$ as the matrices
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ belong to $W_1+W_2$. Therefore
$$\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) = \dim(W_1) + \dim(W_2) - \dim(W_1+W_2) = 2+3 -4=1$$

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong. You wrote that$$W_1\cap W_2=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\},$$but the first matrix of this set does *not* belong to $W_1$. Your friend is right:$$W_1\cap W_2=\mathbb{R}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$and therefore $\dim W_1\cap W_2=1$.

Comment: Now I got it where i was mistaken

Comment: @PriyaWadhwa I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$W_1$ has dimension $2$ but  it is not a subspace of $W_2$, so $W_1 \cap W_2$ cannot have dimension $2$.

Can you see where is your mistake?